# Which Esoterica actions can I use if I choose the Thaumaturge Dedication?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, multi-classing, archetype

The description for Thaumaturgy Dedication states the following (emphasis mine)

> Choose an implement; you can use it to Glimpse Vulnerability, **but don't gain its benefits**. You also gain a few esoterica, **allowing you to use esoterica actions.** You become trained in your choice of Arcana, Nature, Occultism, or Religion; if you were already trained in these, you become trained in a skill of your choice. **You gain the Glimpse Vulnerability action.**

This section tells me I can use “esoterica actions”, which include Exploit Weakness, Intensify Vulnerability, and Glimpse Vulnerability.

However, it confusingly only states that I gain the Glimpse Vulnerability action. Moreover, the Intensify Vulnerability feat contains the following text:

> You gain the intensified vulnerability benefit from one of the implements you're holding

which seems to conflict with the statement that I “do not gain [the implement’s] benefits.

There seems to be a lot of conflicting text here. Which of these actions can I actually use?

Comment: Intensify Vulnerability is not a feat, but a class feature, and it is inaccessible for the archetype

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Thaumaturge Dedication only grants you the Glimpse Vulnerability action

For your first point, you are correct that the phrase "but don't gain its benefits" is referring to the Implement, meaning you don't gain the benefits under their entries under the full Thaumaturge class listing. You can gain access to the Initiate Benefit with the "Implement Initiate" Level 6 archetype feat.

As for the 2nd point, the dedication feat gives you the ability to perform esoterica tagged actions, but doesn't grant you the actions you listed except for Glimpse Vulnerability. Exploit Vulnerability and  Intensify Vulnerability are Class Features and wouldn't be available to you with just the dedication.

Basically, this wording allows you to *use*  actions with the esoterica tag, but you need feats or features that explicitly *grant* you those actions before you can use them.